# InvalidTemplateLibraryError on initial runserver using wagtail

Tags: python, django

Everytime i do
`python manage.py runserver`
an error said

> Invalid template library specified.
>
> ImportError raised when trying to load 'wagtail.wagtailcore.templatetags.wagtailcore_tags': cannot import name _htmlparser

Comment: What is your django and python versions?

Answer (score 3):

There is some bug with new version of html5lib. I found two solutions for this problem:

1. Downgrade html5lib (I tried with version 0.9999999)

> pip uninstall html5lib
>   pip install html5lib==0.9999999

After downgrade everything seems to work perfectly.

2. Temporary fix by editing beautifulsoup4 package file

> <path_to_your_virtualenv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py

At the end of a file you need to comment out next lines:

```
from . import _htmlparser
register_treebuilders_from(_htmlparser)
try:
    from . import _html5lib
    register_treebuilders_from(_html5lib)
except ImportError:
    # They don't have html5lib installed.
    pass
```

After you comment them out wagtail will properly start.

*P.S. I prefer first option.*

**Edit 1:**

Found open GitHub issue: https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/issues/276

Answer (score 0):

You can too add it to your requirements project file, i.e.:

```
wagtail==1.3.1
html5lib==0.9999999
```